# Can't see Android SDK Manager option after Installation; Run as Administrator Doesn't Solve

Tags: android, eclipse

I've seen several solutions to this, but none have yet worked.

I have tried opening Eclipse using "Run as Administrator".  I can go under "Window" and "Preferences" and "Android" and verify navigation to the Android SDK.  I have verified that the file is in that location. I have re-installed, restarted, and rebooted, multiple times.  I have also tried updating Eclipse.

I simply cannot see the option for "Android SDK Manager" under "Window".

I'm new to both Eclipse and Android development, and trying to get the IDE set up for the first time.

I am concerned that a previous mistaken install of Eclipse for C/C++ is the cause.

Comment: I don't know why the option is not under the "Window" menu, but you can run the SDK Manager from the Start Menu. (Right-click icon first and select "Run as Administrator".)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think perspective has been changed by you.

Go to Windows -> Open Perspective->Other and Select "Java(Default)" and click OK.

Comment: I haven't ever changed that option, and I've done multiple installs (which I would think would reset it anyhow).... BUT that was the answer.  Thank you SO much!

Comment: Welcome bro!.Hope this will help others also.

Comment: Don't you just love Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this following:

Window > Custom Perspective (you will see Android and AVD Manager were disable)

Command Groups Availability > Android and AVD Manager > check

Tool Bar Visibility > Android and AVD Manager > check

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Android ADT plugin on eclipse?

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: I did install the Android ADT plugin, following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html.  I have done so following both the web-based, and the later-listed zip-file-based instructions.  I can run the Android SDK Manager independent of Eclipse, so I know it is installed and at least mostly-working.

Comment: Android SDK is independent from ADT. ADT is just a plugin in eclipse to make it easy for Android development... All you have to do is install ADT through eclipse "Install new software..."... You can check if ADT is intalled in eclipse at Help/Install new software/Already installed? ... here should be a list with four android plugins "Android DDMS", "Android Development Tools", "Android traceviwer" and "Android Hierachy Viewer"... if its not there, ADT is not installed.

Comment: I have also done it through the "install new software" option.  In the list under Already Installed I see Android Development Tools and Android DDMS, as the tutorial I was following asked for only those two.  I have, however, also installed all of those tools.  I've also, in another install I tried earlier, installed everything in both the Developer Tools and NDK Plugins options.